# Windows Environment Variables not working

Tags: python-3.x, windows

[image]

I added to PATH the location of python.exe
It doesn't see it. Cant use python in cmd
Also it doesn't see other paths I added

Cant solve this problem for two days now

Comment: When i try entering py in cmd

I get this: Unable to create process using '"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3.8.exe"'

Comment: Fixed it by removing it automatically on the settings page. Under Apps and Features, there are an application execution aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: First go to the apps settings]

[image: Then go to app execution aliases]

All you need to do is disable all the execution aliases for python

Answer (score 1):

Modify the current installation of python by going to "add or delete programs" if you are on windows. There will be an option in the wizard: `Add Python to path`, check it and continue with the modification.

Comment: Done that a few time, done it again now. Still nothing. I did everything correct. It just basically ignores all the paths that are added

Answer (score 0):

@Kra1ven, did you try adding the path manually? And I need the Windows 10 version you're using, so that I can help you more clear...

Comment: Hi. I already fixed the issue. Windows set a default execution alias in the app settings. It was interfering with the paths I had

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a filename in the path.